# Activity layout screen disappears when I add a tab layout

Tags: java, android, ios, render, samsung-mobile

This is how the screen looks, with nothing on it:
[image]

This is how the screen looks, when I add the tab layout:
[image]

I have tried refreshing it, closing the app and opening it again

I get three rendering errors with the following messages:

`Failed to find style with 2131032999`

`Style ResourceReference{namespace=apk/res-auto, type=attr, name=textAppearanceButton} is not of type STYLE (instead attr)`

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:74)
        at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1631)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:874)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3965)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:216)
        at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.setTextAppearance(MaterialTextView.java:106)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3954)
        at androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:289)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.updateTab(TabLayout.java:2772)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2801)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2713)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1673)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:956)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addTabFromItemView(TabLayout.java:824)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1730)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1131)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:443)
        at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:722)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:879)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:194)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:292)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the Material Design library version in your Android Studio project's build.gradle file to a version before 1.8.0.

```html
dependencies {
  'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
 }
```